# angular.element(id).find() is not able to find a child tag

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular project which is hosted here on [github](https://github.com/SarasArya/Angular-Chartist-Tab-Example). It does what it's supposed to do, but there's a piece of code which is supposed to execute but is not executing, here are the lines

```
$scope.tabToggled = function(tab){
    $timeout(function(){
   console.log(angular.element('#'+tab));
        angular.element('#'+tab).find('chartist').each(function(i, e)            {                console.log("Updating");
            e.__chartist__.update();
        });
 }, 100);
 };
```

`Updating` never gets printed in this case.

```
<md-tab ng-repeat="(key, value) in allTheCharts" id="{{key}}" label="{{key}}" md-on-select="tabToggled(key)">'
    <chartist class="ct-chart ct-major-eleventh" chartist-data="value.data" chartist-chart-options="value.options" chartist-chart-type="Bar"></chartist>
</md-tab>
```

this is the markup on which the above code is supposed to run and give output. What is the issue here?

For better insight into code. Checkout the repo. There're just 2 files essentially `index.html` and `app.js`

**Edit**
DOM as seen from developers console

```
<md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex" md-dynamic-height="true" class="ng-isolate-scope md-dynamic-height"><md-tabs-wrapper> <md-tab-data>
            <!-- ngRepeat: (key, value) in allTheCharts --><md-tab ng-repeat="(key, value) in allTheCharts" id="TAB_1" label="TAB_1" md-on-select="tabToggled(key)" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"></md-tab><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in allTheCharts --><md-tab ng-repeat="(key, value) in allTheCharts" id="TAB_2" label="TAB_2" md-on-select="tabToggled(key)" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"></md-tab><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in allTheCharts --><md-tab ng-repeat="(key, value) in allTheCharts" id="TAB_3" label="TAB_3" md-on-select="tabToggled(key)" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"></md-tab><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in allTheCharts -->
        </md-tab-data> <!-- ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.shouldPaginate --> <!-- ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.shouldPaginate --> <md-tabs-canvas tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="tab-item-0" ng-focus="$mdTabsCtrl.redirectFocus()" ng-class="{ 'md-paginated': $mdTabsCtrl.shouldPaginate, 'md-center-tabs': $mdTabsCtrl.shouldCenterTabs }" ng-keydown="$mdTabsCtrl.keydown($event)" role="tablist"> <md-pagination-wrapper ng-class="{ 'md-center-tabs': $mdTabsCtrl.shouldCenterTabs }" md-tab-scroll="$mdTabsCtrl.scroll($event)" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); width: 271px;"> <!-- ngRepeat: tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs --><md-tab-item tabindex="-1" class="md-tab ng-scope ng-isolate-scope md-ink-ripple md-active" ng-repeat="tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-content-0" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false" ng-click="$mdTabsCtrl.select(tab.getIndex())" ng-class="{ 'md-active':    tab.isActive(), 'md-focused':   tab.hasFocus(), 'md-disabled':  tab.scope.disabled }" ng-disabled="tab.scope.disabled" md-swipe-left="$mdTabsCtrl.nextPage()" md-swipe-right="$mdTabsCtrl.previousPage()" md-tabs-template="::tab.label" md-scope="::tab.parent"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">TAB_1</span></md-tab-item><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs --><md-tab-item tabindex="-1" class="md-tab ng-scope ng-isolate-scope md-ink-ripple" ng-repeat="tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-content-1" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" ng-click="$mdTabsCtrl.select(tab.getIndex())" ng-class="{ 'md-active':    tab.isActive(), 'md-focused':   tab.hasFocus(), 'md-disabled':  tab.scope.disabled }" ng-disabled="tab.scope.disabled" md-swipe-left="$mdTabsCtrl.nextPage()" md-swipe-right="$mdTabsCtrl.previousPage()" md-tabs-template="::tab.label" md-scope="::tab.parent"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">TAB_2</span></md-tab-item><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs --><md-tab-item tabindex="-1" class="md-tab ng-scope ng-isolate-scope md-ink-ripple" ng-repeat="tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-content-2" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" ng-click="$mdTabsCtrl.select(tab.getIndex())" ng-class="{ 'md-active':    tab.isActive(), 'md-focused':   tab.hasFocus(), 'md-disabled':  tab.scope.disabled }" ng-disabled="tab.scope.disabled" md-swipe-left="$mdTabsCtrl.nextPage()" md-swipe-right="$mdTabsCtrl.previousPage()" md-tabs-template="::tab.label" md-scope="::tab.parent"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">TAB_3</span></md-tab-item><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs --> <md-ink-bar style="left: 0px; right: 181px;"></md-ink-bar> </md-pagination-wrapper> <div class="md-visually-hidden md-dummy-wrapper"> <!-- ngRepeat: tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs --><md-dummy-tab class="md-tab ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" tabindex="-1" id="tab-item-0" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-content-0" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false" ng-focus="$mdTabsCtrl.hasFocus = true" ng-blur="$mdTabsCtrl.hasFocus = false" ng-repeat="tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" md-tabs-template="::tab.label" md-scope="::tab.parent"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">TAB_1</span></md-dummy-tab><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs --><md-dummy-tab class="md-tab ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" tabindex="-1" id="tab-item-1" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-content-1" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" ng-focus="$mdTabsCtrl.hasFocus = true" ng-blur="$mdTabsCtrl.hasFocus = false" ng-repeat="tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" md-tabs-template="::tab.label" md-scope="::tab.parent"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">TAB_2</span></md-dummy-tab><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs --><md-dummy-tab class="md-tab ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" tabindex="-1" id="tab-item-2" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-content-2" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" ng-focus="$mdTabsCtrl.hasFocus = true" ng-blur="$mdTabsCtrl.hasFocus = false" ng-repeat="tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" md-tabs-template="::tab.label" md-scope="::tab.parent"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">TAB_3</span></md-dummy-tab><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs --> </div> </md-tabs-canvas> </md-tabs-wrapper> <md-tabs-content-wrapper ng-show="$mdTabsCtrl.hasContent &amp;&amp; $mdTabsCtrl.selectedIndex >= 0" aria-hidden="false" class=""> <!-- ngRepeat: (index, tab) in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs --><!-- ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.hasContent --><md-tab-content id="tab-content-0" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-item-0" md-swipe-left="$mdTabsCtrl.swipeContent &amp;&amp; $mdTabsCtrl.incrementIndex(1)" md-swipe-right="$mdTabsCtrl.swipeContent &amp;&amp; $mdTabsCtrl.incrementIndex(-1)" ng-if="$mdTabsCtrl.hasContent" ng-repeat="(index, tab) in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" ng-class="{ 'md-no-transition': $mdTabsCtrl.lastSelectedIndex == null, 'md-active':        tab.isActive(), 'md-left':          tab.isLeft(), 'md-right':         tab.isRight(), 'md-no-scroll':     $mdTabsCtrl.dynamicHeight }" class="ng-scope md-no-transition md-active md-no-scroll"> <!-- ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.enableDisconnect || tab.shouldRender() --><div md-tabs-template="::tab.template" md-connected-if="tab.isActive()" md-scope="::tab.parent" ng-if="$mdTabsCtrl.enableDisconnect || tab.shouldRender()" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
                <chartist class="ct-chart ct-major-eleventh ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" chartist-data="value.data" chartist-chart-options="value.options" chartist-chart-type="Bar"><svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="100%" height="100%" class="ct-chart-bar" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><g class="ct-grids"><line x1="50" x2="50" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="222.4" x2="222.4" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="394.8" x2="394.8" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="567.2" x2="567.2" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="739.6" x2="739.6" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line y1="312.625" y2="312.625" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="263.0208333333333" y2="263.0208333333333" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="213.41666666666669" y2="213.41666666666669" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="163.8125" y2="163.8125" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="114.20833333333334" y2="114.20833333333334" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="64.60416666666666" y2="64.60416666666666" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="15" y2="15" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line></g><g><g class="ct-series ct-series-a"><line x1="136.2" x2="136.2" y1="312.625" y2="292.78333333333336" class="ct-bar" value="1"></line><line x1="308.6" x2="308.6" y1="312.625" y2="114.20833333333334" class="ct-bar" value="10"></line><line x1="481" x2="481" y1="312.625" y2="54.68333333333334" class="ct-bar" value="13"></line><line x1="653.4000000000001" x2="653.4000000000001" y1="312.625" y2="213.41666666666669" class="ct-bar" value="5"></line><line x1="825.8000000000001" x2="825.8000000000001" y1="312.625" y2="253.1" class="ct-bar" value="3"></line></g></g><g class="ct-labels"><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="50" y="317.625" width="172.4" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Mon</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="222.4" y="317.625" width="172.4" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Tue</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="394.8" y="317.625" width="172.40000000000003" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Wed</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="567.2" y="317.625" width="172.39999999999998" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Thur</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="739.6" y="317.625" width="172.39999999999998" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Fri</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="263.0208333333333" x="10" height="49.604166666666664" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 50px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">0</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="213.41666666666666" x="10" height="49.604166666666664" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 50px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">2.5</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="163.8125" x="10" height="49.60416666666667" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 50px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">5</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="114.20833333333334" x="10" height="49.60416666666666" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 50px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">7.5</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="64.60416666666666" x="10" height="49.604166666666686" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 50px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">10</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="15" x="10" height="49.60416666666666" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 50px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">12.5</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="-15" x="10" height="30" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 30px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">15</span></foreignObject></g></svg></chartist>
            </div><!-- end ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.enableDisconnect || tab.shouldRender() --> </md-tab-content><!-- end ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.hasContent --><!-- end ngRepeat: (index, tab) in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs --><!-- ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.hasContent --><md-tab-content id="tab-content-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-item-1" md-swipe-left="$mdTabsCtrl.swipeContent &amp;&amp; $mdTabsCtrl.incrementIndex(1)" md-swipe-right="$mdTabsCtrl.swipeContent &amp;&amp; $mdTabsCtrl.incrementIndex(-1)" ng-if="$mdTabsCtrl.hasContent" ng-repeat="(index, tab) in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" ng-class="{ 'md-no-transition': $mdTabsCtrl.lastSelectedIndex == null, 'md-active':        tab.isActive(), 'md-left':          tab.isLeft(), 'md-right':         tab.isRight(), 'md-no-scroll':     $mdTabsCtrl.dynamicHeight }" class="ng-scope md-no-transition md-right md-no-scroll"> <!-- ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.enableDisconnect || tab.shouldRender() --><div md-tabs-template="::tab.template" md-connected-if="tab.isActive()" md-scope="::tab.parent" ng-if="$mdTabsCtrl.enableDisconnect || tab.shouldRender()" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
                <chartist class="ct-chart ct-major-eleventh ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" chartist-data="value.data" chartist-chart-options="value.options" chartist-chart-type="Bar"><svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="100%" height="100%" class="ct-chart-bar" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><g class="ct-grids"><line x1="50" x2="50" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="222.4" x2="222.4" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="394.8" x2="394.8" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="567.2" x2="567.2" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="739.6" x2="739.6" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line y1="312.625" y2="312.625" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="275.421875" y2="275.421875" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="238.21875" y2="238.21875" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="201.015625" y2="201.015625" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="163.8125" y2="163.8125" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="126.609375" y2="126.609375" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="89.40625" y2="89.40625" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="52.203125" y2="52.203125" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="15" y2="15" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line></g><g><g class="ct-series ct-series-a"><line x1="136.2" x2="136.2" y1="312.625" y2="238.21875" class="ct-bar" value="20"></line><line x1="308.6" x2="308.6" y1="312.625" y2="275.421875" class="ct-bar" value="10"></line><line x1="481" x2="481" y1="312.625" y2="201.015625" class="ct-bar" value="30"></line><line x1="653.4000000000001" x2="653.4000000000001" y1="312.625" y2="163.8125" class="ct-bar" value="40"></line><line x1="825.8000000000001" x2="825.8000000000001" y1="312.625" y2="15" class="ct-bar" value="80"></line></g></g><g class="ct-labels"><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="50" y="317.625" width="172.4" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Mon</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="222.4" y="317.625" width="172.4" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Tue</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="394.8" y="317.625" width="172.40000000000003" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Wed</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="567.2" y="317.625" width="172.39999999999998" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Thur</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="739.6" y="317.625" width="172.39999999999998" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Fri</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="275.421875" x="10" height="37.203125" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 37px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">0</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="238.21875" x="10" height="37.203125" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 37px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">10</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="201.015625" x="10" height="37.203125" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 37px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">20</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="163.8125" x="10" height="37.203125" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 37px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">30</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="126.609375" x="10" height="37.203125" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 37px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">40</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="89.40625" x="10" height="37.203125" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 37px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">50</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="52.203125" x="10" height="37.203125" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 37px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">60</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="15" x="10" height="37.203125" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 37px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">70</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="-15" x="10" height="30" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 30px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">80</span></foreignObject></g></svg></chartist>
            </div><!-- end ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.enableDisconnect || tab.shouldRender() --> </md-tab-content><!-- end ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.hasContent --><!-- end ngRepeat: (index, tab) in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs --><!-- ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.hasContent --><md-tab-content id="tab-content-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-item-2" md-swipe-left="$mdTabsCtrl.swipeContent &amp;&amp; $mdTabsCtrl.incrementIndex(1)" md-swipe-right="$mdTabsCtrl.swipeContent &amp;&amp; $mdTabsCtrl.incrementIndex(-1)" ng-if="$mdTabsCtrl.hasContent" ng-repeat="(index, tab) in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" ng-class="{ 'md-no-transition': $mdTabsCtrl.lastSelectedIndex == null, 'md-active':        tab.isActive(), 'md-left':          tab.isLeft(), 'md-right':         tab.isRight(), 'md-no-scroll':     $mdTabsCtrl.dynamicHeight }" class="ng-scope md-no-transition md-right md-no-scroll"> <!-- ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.enableDisconnect || tab.shouldRender() --><div md-tabs-template="::tab.template" md-connected-if="tab.isActive()" md-scope="::tab.parent" ng-if="$mdTabsCtrl.enableDisconnect || tab.shouldRender()" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
                <chartist class="ct-chart ct-major-eleventh ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" chartist-data="value.data" chartist-chart-options="value.options" chartist-chart-type="Bar"><svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="100%" height="100%" class="ct-chart-bar" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><g class="ct-grids"><line x1="50" x2="50" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="222.4" x2="222.4" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="394.8" x2="394.8" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="567.2" x2="567.2" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="739.6" x2="739.6" y1="15" y2="312.625" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line y1="312.625" y2="312.625" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="270.10714285714283" y2="270.10714285714283" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="227.58928571428572" y2="227.58928571428572" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="185.07142857142856" y2="185.07142857142856" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="142.55357142857142" y2="142.55357142857142" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="100.03571428571428" y2="100.03571428571428" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="57.51785714285714" y2="57.51785714285714" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="15" y2="15" x1="50" x2="912" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line></g><g><g class="ct-series ct-series-a"><line x1="136.2" x2="136.2" y1="312.625" y2="304.12142857142857" class="ct-bar" value="1"></line><line x1="308.6" x2="308.6" y1="312.625" y2="227.58928571428572" class="ct-bar" value="10"></line><line x1="481" x2="481" y1="312.625" y2="23.503571428571433" class="ct-bar" value="34"></line><line x1="653.4000000000001" x2="653.4000000000001" y1="312.625" y2="270.10714285714283" class="ct-bar" value="5"></line><line x1="825.8000000000001" x2="825.8000000000001" y1="312.625" y2="287.1142857142857" class="ct-bar" value="3"></line></g></g><g class="ct-labels"><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="50" y="317.625" width="172.4" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Mon</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="222.4" y="317.625" width="172.4" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Tue</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="394.8" y="317.625" width="172.40000000000003" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Wed</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="567.2" y="317.625" width="172.39999999999998" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Thur</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="739.6" y="317.625" width="172.39999999999998" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 172px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Fri</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="270.10714285714283" x="10" height="42.517857142857146" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 43px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">0</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="227.5892857142857" x="10" height="42.517857142857146" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 43px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">5</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="185.07142857142858" x="10" height="42.51785714285714" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 43px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">10</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="142.5535714285714" x="10" height="42.51785714285715" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 43px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">15</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="100.03571428571428" x="10" height="42.51785714285714" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 43px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">20</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="57.51785714285714" x="10" height="42.51785714285714" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 43px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">25</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="15" x="10" height="42.51785714285714" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 43px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">30</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="-15" x="10" height="30" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 30px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">35</span></foreignObject></g></svg></chartist>
            </div><!-- end ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.enableDisconnect || tab.shouldRender() --> </md-tab-content><!-- end ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.hasContent --><!-- end ngRepeat: (index, tab) in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs --> </md-tabs-content-wrapper></md-tabs>
```

Comment: The markup is irrelevant. What does the DOM look like at the time the function is called?

Comment: You can see the DOM now. this is how it looks. I copied it from the Elements Tab of Developers console.

Comment: In the DOM `chartist` is no longer a descendant of `md-tab`. Accessing the DOM outside a directive is a hack anyway. Shouldn't `chartist` update itself automatically?

Comment: There is an issue with chartist. [this](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/119) is the link. I got the solution from here but it doesn't work for angularJS

Comment: I tried with the solution @phil gave me. But I seem to be no where. I created a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/IMUucs5RdQrYB8jftXRw?p=preview) for the same. Could you check this out and help me find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is to assign an id to the `chartist` elements:

```
<chartist id="chart-{{key}}"
```

In your JavaScript can you can then refer to an element by id:

```
    $scope.tabToggled = function(tab) {
        console.log(angular.element('#chart-'+tab));
        $('#chart'+tab).each(function(i, e) {
            console.log("Updating");
            e.__chartist__.update();
        });
```

If `key` contains illegal characters you can use the index instead:

```
<md-tab ng-repeat="(key, value) in allTheCharts" md-on-select="tabToggled($index)">
  <chartist id="chart-{{$index}}"
```

Comment: could you edit the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NXJNIRLoItlM9oBAZfjJ?p=preview) because it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @SarasArya You no longer need to call `.find('chartist')`

Comment: yes... I figured that out... Thank you so much for the help